# Laravel Lighthouse - Receive Eloquent Builder instead of Query Builder in handleBuilder method?

Tags: laravel, graphql, lighthouse, laravel-lighthouse, graphql-php

Is there a way to receive an instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` instead of `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` in the `handleBuilder` method when creating a custom `ArgBuilderDirective`?

See [this example](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/custom-directives/argument-directives.html#argbuilderdirective):

```php
<?php

namespace Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Directives;

use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\ArgBuilderDirective;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\DefinedDirective;

class EqDirective extends BaseDirective implements ArgBuilderDirective, DefinedDirective
{
    /**
     * Name of the directive.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function name(): string
    {
        return 'eq';
    }

    /**
     * Apply a "WHERE = $value" clause.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function handleBuilder($builder, $value)
    {
        // $builder is an instance of \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder here.
        // Is it possible to receive an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder instead?
        return $builder->where(
            $this->directiveArgValue('key', $this->nodeName()),
            $value
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure? the docs says builder is already a eloquest/builder

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. I have tried it and I receive an instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.